# Is "python2" / "python3" safe on a script's shebang?

Tags: python, scripting, portability, shebang

Sometimes I see `#!/usr/bin/python2` and `#!/usr/bin/python3` as opposed to simply `#!/usr/bin/python`. I get the appeal of this approach, you get to explicitly say if you need Python 2 or 3 without doing some weird version checking.

Are these `python2` and `python3` standard though? Will they work everywhere? Or is it risky?

I just confirmed I have `python2` and `python3` but I am on Cygwin so I wouldn't think this means it's necessarily the same for a lot of others.

---

**Note:** To anyone considering `#!/usr/bin/python` with or without a number, a more important thing to remember is that `python` isn't even always in `/usr/bin` (FreeBSD and OSX for example), so use `#!/usr/bin/env python` if you want to most portability.

Then just pray that `env` is in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: you'd only have that if you have MULTIPLE python versions installed and need to explicitly call one or the other.

Comment: It may be worth saying that you should use `env` in your shebang if you want more portability concerning executable targets. Not every python installation defaults in `/usr` (I can tell you it doesn't happen in FreeBSD and Mac OSX).

Comment: @farsil thanks, I can add that in. I do have one question though about using `env` in shebangs, is `#!/usr/bin/env ...` correct or is `env` installed in varying locations also?

Comment: To the best my knowledge, there is no strict standard about the location of `env`. However, it is more likely to find `env` in `/usr/bin` compared to most other programs across multiple OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a single point of reference -- I don't have a `python2` executable on my system:

```
$ python2
-bash: python2: command not found
```

So I would definitely not consider this one to be portable.  Obviously I could still run your script by selecting an executable explicitly:

```
python2.7 your_script.py
```

Or by symlinking `python2` to `python2.7`, but the point is that it won't work out of the box for me (and I imagine for a number of other users as well).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what OS?

Comment: @CaptainMan -- OS-X

Comment: Also out of curiosity, is `python2.7` "standard" or another convenient soft link a package maintainer made?

Comment: I think it's pretty common, but I wouldn't depend on it.  Remember -- These things can vary greatly depending on what flavor/flavors of python the user has installed.  e.g. if there was a system out there without CPython but with Pypy, you'd need to use `pypy` rather than python.  I think that the shebang is really just convenience and you probably shouldn't worry about it _too_ much (your script can still be run no matter what it is in the shebang as long as the user has the correct python installed _somewhere_).